# Truncate a value in JSON script

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I'm creating a stock widget, using JSON to get data from the Yahoo API/YQL console. I am using values from the key ChangePercentRealtime, but the values are longer than I need. How can I truncate the value down to the portion I need, which is the latter percentage? I have no idea how to accomplish this, and a Google search hasn't turned anything useful up.

Here is what I've got so far: http://jsfiddle.net/thetuneupguy/r2Bca/

```
$(function () {
    $.getJSON('http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=SELECT%20*%20FROM%20yahoo.finance.quotes%20WHERE%20symbol%20in(%22GCF14.CMX%22%2C%22SIF14.CMX%22%2C%22PAH14.NYM%22%2C%22PLF14.NYM%22)&format=json&diagnostics=true&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys&callback=', function (data) {
    console.log("data: ", data);
    console.log(data.query.results.quote);
    $.each(data.query.results.quote, function (key, obj) {
        var changeClass = '';
        var changeInPercentClass = '';
        var $tr = $('<tr/>', {
            'class': 'my-new-list'
        }).appendTo('#blk-1 table');
        $tr.append($('<td/>').text(obj.Name || "--"));
        $tr.append($('<td/>').text(obj.AskRealtime || "--"));
        $tr.append($('<td/>').text(obj.BidRealtime || "--"));

        (obj.Change.substr(0,1) == '+') ? changeClass = 'green' : changeClass = 'red';

        (obj.Change.substr(0,1) == '+') ? changeInPercentClass = 'green' : changeInPercentClass = 'red';

        $tr.append($('<td class="'+changeClass+'">').text(obj.ChangeRealtime|| "--"));
        $tr.append($('<td class="'+changeInPercentClass+'">').text(obj.ChangePercentRealtime || "--"));
        });

    });
});
```

Comment: Eh? Hrm? What are you asking?  What, exactly, are you trying to truncate down? And how would you like it truncated?

Comment: In the Change% column are values similar to this: N/A - +1.10%. I only need the latter percentage, so in this example +1.10% is needed, and the remaining characters and spaces are not.

Comment: I am looking at .slice(), but I don't think that is practical in this case, because the numbers will change decimal values. Is there a way to look for the + or - sign and take that and everything after it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a regular expression to find the data that you want:

```
var re = /([+|-]\d\.\d\d\%)/gi;
var rt = re.exec(obj.ChangePercentRealtime);
$tr.append($('<td class="'+changeInPercentClass+'">').text( rt[0] || "--"));
```

I've updated [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r2Bca/9/) and there is no error catching so you will need to implement that yourself.

Comment: Ha! I was just working on using `.test()` to search `ChangePercentRealtime` for "N/A - " and then if that came back true to assign it a variable and delete that variable. Yours seems a bit less complex, which I like.